# Scroll down on a list by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I would like to be able to scroll down on a list by clicking a button.

I'm using this JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dely/TN4wP/14/)

but that scrolls down the entire page. I would like to have it scroll a list instead, I started on it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TN4wP/37/), but it doesn't work. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <input type="button" value="Scroll" id="scroll" />
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
           ...
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#scroll').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: '+=400'
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list won't scroll because the list is already at 100%.  For it to scroll, you have to put it in a separate container (the div) set a height for it and then scroll the div, not the list or the html.

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/TN4wP/38/

I added some css for the div

```
#scroll {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.box{
height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and I changed the animation to work on  only the div

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#scroll').click(function () {
        $('.box').animate({
            scrollTop: '+=100'
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

this should get you started